# Does anything like Combo-box in android

Tags: android, combobox, radio-button

I need something like comboBox in android that have DisplayMember and ValueMember but for RadioButtons. I have a form that user should select one item, and I want to save the selected item in database. (the code of selected Item).
What should I do?

Comment: You can create custom dialog for your combo box

Comment: `anything like Combo-box in android` It's called **Spinner**...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setSingleChoiceItems property of alert dialog, which have radio buttons as you needed in question.
Check [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8836be/adding-alertdialog-with-setsinglechoiceitems-in-android/) example, it may help you.
Here is another [link](http://www.bipinrupadiya.com/2013/08/android-alertdialog-setsinglechoiceitem.html)

Comment: Hi. The link is broken

Comment: Remove the bracket at the end of the link and it works

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at **Spinner**,
Here's example about it http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

If u want something like radiobutton but can choose only one, use **RadioGrop**.
Or you can create your own dialog with radio button.

Comment: in Spinner or RadioGroup can I set the value Member and Display member?

Comment: I dont clearly about value Member and Display member, you mean when user chose display member, you will take respective value member and save this to database ? it can do.

Comment: it's not easy, pleas google with key "custom spinner android"

Comment: yes. But how can I use it? Do you have any example ?

Comment: Ok . I will search it.